# How to list all the linux aliases

Tags: linux, go, alias, subshell

I am aware that in Linux I can use the `alias` command to get a list of defined aliases. I am now trying to do the same through Go code with:

```
func ListAlias() error {
    out, err := exec.Command("alias").Output()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println(out)
    return nil
}
```

but all that were returned were:

```
exec: "alias": executable file not found in $PATH
```

I tried looking for where the actual binary of `alias` is but that leads nowhere either:

```
$whereis alias
alias:
```

The alternative I've considered is to parse the `~/.bashrc` file for the list of aliases defined but I have encountered this scenario where the `bashrc` lists another `custom_aliases.sh` file and all the aliases are listed there. That's why I am trying to use the `alias` command to list all the aliases.

Comment: For what it's worth: `alias` is a Bash built-in, so isn't a command you can run outside the shell.

Comment: That said, you can run `exec.Command("bash", "-ic", "alias")`.

Comment: This also begs the question, why? We can't prevent naive users from prefering aliases when they shouldn't, but very often, the answer to any question about aliases is "don't; put the logic in a shell script or function".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`alias` isn't an executable but a [shell builtin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_builtin). You can easily see that by running

```
$ type alias
alias is a shell builtin
```

Therefore you need to call the shell's `alias` command depending on which shell you're using. For example with `bash` you'll need to use

```
out, err := exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-c", "alias").Output()
```

But that still won't give you the answer because [bash doesn't `source` the `.bashrc` file in that case](https://superuser.com/q/1300875/241386) so aliases won't be available in the subshell. You'll need the `--rcfile` or `--login`/`-l` option and also need to [specify the shell as interactive with `-i`](https://superuser.com/a/671488/241386)

```
out, err := exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-lic", "alias").Output()
// or
out, err := exec.Command("/bin/bash", "--rcfile", "~/.bashrc", "-ic", "alias").Output()
```

`exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-ic", "alias")` would also possibly work depending on where your aliases are sourced. Other shells like zsh, sh, dash... may source different files with different options, so check your shell's documentation if `-ic` or `-lic` doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$compgen -a
```

`-a` tell the command `compgen` to list all alias

or

```
$alias
```